# Navigating in a LOAD component

Tags: web2py

I created a form using SQLFORM and inserted into the view a LOAD component that contains another SQLFORM that displays the content of the table being populated by filling and submitting the form.

It looks something like:
-Form field 1
-Form field 2
....
-Component
-Form button 1

This works well, however, when the number of entries to be displayed by the component exceed 20 a new page is created and arrows appear to navigate between the pages.
The problem is that if I use the arrows to go to the next page I'm redirected to another webpage that contains the SQLFORM of the component.

Is there any way of navigating between the pages while staying on the form?

I could try to circumvent the problem by setting the *paginate* value to a value higher than 20 but it would still be problematic at some point.

Synthetic version of the code:

**View:**

```
{{response.files.append('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js')}}
    {{extend 'layout.html'}}

    {{=form.custom.begin}}
    {{=LOAD('default','intermediate.load', ajax=True, target="intermediate")}}
    {{=form.custom.submit}}
    {{=form.custom.end}}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#field_1').change( function(){
                ajax('reload_intermediate', ['field_1'], ':eval');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**Controller:**

```
def form_1():
    form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('field_1'),
    Field('field_2'),
    buttons = [INPUT(_type='button',_id='btn_add',_value ='Do')])
    return dict(form=form)

def reload_intermediate():
        value = request.vars.field_1
        return '''$("#intermediate").load('intermediate.load?value={}');'''.format(value)
```

**Component:**

```
{{  form_results_grid = SQLFORM.grid(db(db.Table_1.id == request.vars.value),create=False,searchable=False, details=False, deletable=False, editable=False, csv=False, user_signature=False, maxtextlength=100)
}}
{{=form_results_grid}}
```

The component, called *intermediate* here, works well but doesn't allow for navigation between pages without being redirected into the component itself, thus leaving the page with the form.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: @Anthony: I added some code to illustrate how it is built. Let me know if this is enough. Ty.

Comment: Instead of reloading the component via `$("#intermediate").load('intermediate.load?value={}');`, having you tried using `"$.web2py.component('%s', 'intermediate');" % URL('intermediate.load', vars=dict(value=request.vars.value))`?

Comment: @Anthony: I just tried it, and though I see the exact same GET being sent it fails to display the component in the view. Would it change how the component work anyway? It seems to me that's where the problem lies (or maybe it isn't).